# Padronizar número de telefone no Python

Tags: python, regex

Estou tentando padronizar a coluna 'Número' do seguinte dataset:

```
Alunos  Número
Amanda  +5585988001677
Amon    85 85460364
Ana     85 99221-8211
Ananda  (85) 9862-64842
Antonio (85)987989342
Antônia 85 9852-36542
Antônio 85 9971 19741
Beatriz 85986124985
Cândida 85 985374355
Dalete  85988881389
Daniel  85999202078
```

Gostaria de deixar todos no seguinte formato: `85989989342` sem nenhum caractere ou espaço.
Utilizei então o seguinte código:

```
import pandas as pd

colunanumeros = tabela['Número']

r = re.compile(r'\D')
n = (r.sub("", str(colunanumeros)))
```

O problema é que quando eu dou um print em 'n', os numeros vem todos juntos como o exemplo abaixo:

```
print(n) #1385585988001677139858546036492859922182111678598626489314385987989394180859875425061169894754162785987036376164884679091458898832000086
```

Eu gostaria de saber, como faço para que a saída seja os números separados.

EX: `5585988001677, 8585456521,. 85989276545`

Não sei se criando uma lista talvez. Tenho pesquisado mas ainda estou engatinhando em algumas coisas.

Estou usando o Pandas.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o replace do pandas passando um regex(caso você esteja utilizando o pandas, isso não ficou claro na sua pergunta): `df['Número'] = df['Número'].str.replace('\D', '', regex=True)`

Comment: Certo. Vou tentar. E sim, estou usando o Pandas. Perdão pela pobre elaboração da pergunta. Estou melhorando.

Comment: @GuyFawkes05th, vale a pena editar a pergunta e adicionar o fato de que vc estah usando pandas (e alterar o codigo do primeiro exemplo de acordo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muito obrigado, imonferrari. Eu fiz como sugerido em seu comentário:

```
tabela['Número] = tabela['Número'].str.replace('\D','', regex=True)
```

e deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a biblioteca phonenumbers, que é um porte não oficial da Google libphonenumbers (JAVA, C++, Javascript);

https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers

exemplo:

```py
import pandas as pd
from phonenumbers import PhoneNumberFormat, parse as phone_parse, format_number as phone_format
from io import StringIO

csv = """Alunos;Número
Amanda;+5585988001677
Amon;85 85460364
Ana;85 99221-8211
Ananda;(85) 9862-64842
Antonio;(85)987989342
Antônia;85 9852-36542
Antônio;85 9971 19741
Beatriz;85986124985
Cândida;85 985374355
Dalete;85988881389
Daniel;85999202078
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), sep=';')

df['Número'] = df['Número'].apply(lambda n: phone_format(phone_parse(n, 'BR'), PhoneNumberFormat.E164))

df
```

A saída deve ser:

```
Alunos  Número
0   Amanda  +5585988001677
1   Amon    +558585460364
2   Ana     +5585992218211
3   Ananda  +5585986264842
4   Antonio +5585987989342
5   Antônia +5585985236542
6   Antônio +5585997119741
7   Beatriz +5585986124985
8   Cândida +5585985374355
9   Dalete  +5585988881389
10  Daniel  +5585999202078
```

Os padrões para formatação são:

```
PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL   (Padrão internacional)
PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL        (Padrão do país do número, sem o DDI)
PhoneNumberFormat.E164            (Padrão internacional sem espaços e hífen)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Vagner. Não conhecia a Lib.